# How do I find out when badges were awarded to me?

Tags: support

I got quite a nice collection of badges in the mean time, so I pretty much lost the overview when which badge was awarded to me. I tried hovering over the badges on the badges-page of my profile, but that didn't reveal when the badge was awarded to me.

Ho do I know when I received a badge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also with [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139470/178505), you can see in `activity tab-> badges subtab` in your profile.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Click on a badge on your profile

[image]

You'll see the date there:

[image]

Note that the badges were not awarded all at once.

Comment: Activity page should also work.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the badge. The page will tell you when you got it (or the multiple times when you did).